# Tangents to Polar Curves

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

I am given the polar curve $r=3cos(θ)$. I am to list all of the points (three in total) $(r,θ)$ where the tangent line is horizontal.

From $r=3cos(θ)$, I was able to derive that

$$x = rcos(\theta) = 3cos(\theta)cos(\theta) = 3cos^2(\theta)$$

$$y = rsin(\theta) = 3cos(\theta)sin(\theta)$$

Therefore
$$\frac{dy}{d\theta} = 3cos(\theta)(cos(\theta)) + sin(\theta)(-3sin\theta) = 3cos^2(\theta)-3sin^2(\theta)$$

The question asks for where the tangent line is horizontal. I know that a tangent line is horizontal when $\frac{dy}{d\theta} = 0$, so I plugged that into my equation.

$$3cos^2(\theta)-3sin^2(\theta) = 0$$

$$cos^2(\theta) - sin^2(\theta) = 0$$

For the difference between $cos^2(x) and sin^2(x)$ to the zero, then $cos^2(x) = sin^2(x)$. Such a phenomenon only occurs every 1/8th of the unit circle.

$$:. \theta = \pi/4, 3\pi/4, 5\pi/4, 7\pi/4 \quad etc$$

However, most of these are apparently wrong.

Plugging in $\theta = \pi/4$ to come up with $(r,\theta)$ = $(3\frac{\sqrt2}{2},\theta)$ is correct, but $3\pi/4$ and $5\pi/4 $ are not correct.

I'm confused as to what else the answers could possible be. Please help in any way you can.

Comment: I think there is an issue in the question.  I plotted $r = 3\cos(\theta)$ (which is a circle), and there are only two points where the tangent to the curve is horizontal.

Comment: Actually, the horizontal line occurs where $\frac{dy}{dx}$ becomes $0$. Thus, since this derivative is $\frac{dy}{d\theta}$ divided by $\frac{dx}{d\theta}$, you have to account for the denominator, i.e., $\frac{dx}{d\theta}$, not being $0$. For more details, please check the similar answered question at [Polar tangents of $x = cos(3 \theta)$, $y = 5sin(\theta)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3140633/polar-tangents-of-x-cos3-theta-y-5sin-theta/3140751).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mention in my comment, the horizontal line actually occurs where $\frac{dy}{dx}$ becomes $0$. Thus, since this derivative is $\frac{dy}{d\theta}$ divided by $\frac{dx}{d\theta}$, to be fully correct, you have to ensure that the denominator, i.e., $\frac{dx}{d\theta}$, is not $0$. However, that's not the case here as $\frac{dx}{d\theta} = -6\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)$.

The actual issue is that $r = 3\cos(\theta)$ **must** be non-negative. This is because $r$ is the distance from the origin in the Cartesian coordinate plane and distances are always non-negative. Thus, some of your proposed values of $\theta$ are not allowed if $\cos(\theta)$ is negative. In particular, this limits the range of $\theta$ to being in the first & fourth quadrants, e.g., $-\frac{\pi}{2} \lt \theta \lt \frac{\pi}{2}$ or $\frac{3\pi}{2} \lt \theta \lt \frac{5\pi}{2}$, so values like $\frac{3\pi}{4}$ and $\frac{5\pi}{4}$ are not included as they're in the second & third quadrants.

Comment: Yep, this works. Except $7\pi/4$ _does_ have a positive cosine value, so it's one of the answers. My question is _why_ must $3cos(\theta)$ be non-negative?

Comment: @CodingMee Sorry about that, I made a mistake in considering the quadrant of $7\pi/4$. I have corrected my answer accordingly, plus expanded it slightly.

Comment: @CodingMee In polar coordinates, $r$ is defined to be the *distance* of a point in the Cartesian coordinate plane from the origin. Note that distances are always non-negative values. Since $r$ is defined to be $3\cos(\theta)$, this means the equation only applies & is valid when $3\cos(\theta) \ge 0$.

Comment: @CodingMee I agree that $7\pi/4$ is one of the answers. However, note your question text in the second last paragraph says that it is not a correct answer.

Comment: It was wrong back then because I needed to write the answers in a certain order, but I've fixed it thank you

Comment: @CodingMee You are welcome. Note that I've added about $r$ being non-negative to my answer to help make it more complete for anybody else reading it who may also be wondering why that is the case.